# Is there any way to get ios4 simulators on Xcode 4.4.1 Mountain Lion?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

Firstly I will explain my problem with trying to an support ios4+ app on Xcode 4.4.1, then I have 3 questions below, I appreciate any answers that may help me.

I have happily used various versions of Xcode for a while and recently upgraded to Xcode 4.4.1 and ML. In the past it has always been possible to copy in the older simulator sdks to the relevant folder in the Xcode package contents, this technique no longer works.

The advertisement for Xcode 4.4.1 reads with this extract:

"Xcode includes a new 'Downloads' preference pane to install optional components such as command line tools, and previous iOS Simulators"

This convinced me that I would be able to get old simulators to work, but in my experience this far, you can only get one singular old simulator (ios 5.0). The extract above would indicate you could get access to more than one old simulator as it uses the plural "previous ios simulators".

**EDIT**

You may also get the option to download ios4.3 simulator if you have updated to Xcode 4.4.1 before installing Mountain Lion. However the simulator will not work once you have ML and 4.4.1.

**END EDIT**

I have been able to test using a personal device (iphone) running ios4.3 but this is not an ideal way for me to test. I support down to ios4.0 so ideally like to check my code with ios simulators for ios4.0, ios4.1, ios4.2, and ios4.3.

I like to use the latest Xcode and ML but it seems my best option may be to roll back to an older Xcode on Lion.

Questions

1) Is there any way to get functional ios4 simulators on Xcode 4.4.1 Mountain Lion?

2) Are there any plans to allow ios4 simulators in a new version or have Apple deliberately blocked this?

3) Are there other developers in this position, that can advise what is the best measure? Are people holding off / rolling back from Xcode 4.4.1 on ML?

Thanks

**SECOND EDIT - My Work Around Solution**

As I have had it confirmed ios4 simulators are not supported on Xcode 4.4.1 (ML) and the advice is you should test on a device.

I decided I still needed a version of lion with xcode 4.3.3 on it somewhere so I could access ios 4 simulators. Therefore on my imac I set up a virtual machine via vmware that run osx 10.7 lion. On this virtual machine I installed Xcode 4.3.3 and the old simulators now I have them available for when I want to test any ios4 issues :).

This solution has cost me 28gb in memory space on my imac but Im happy I have mountain lion running on my main machine and a virtual machine with lion running and xcode 4.3.3. It may seem like a lot of trouble but what are the other options?

Another solution is maybe ask the user Popeye how he is claiming to have done it. I have tried to find out but not got anything apart from irrelevant information and requests to delete the question.

**END SECOND EDIT**

Comment: From what I understand should you not just be able to go to xcode >> Preferences >> Downloads and just download the ios4 sdk.

Comment: Since you have stated you can download the 4.3 simulator this needs updating to inform readers of this as this question gives the impression you can't download any.

Comment: I have updated 3 Macs to ML and Xcode 4.4.1. On one occasion I had the option to download simulator 4.3 (which didnt work once downloaded). On the other 2 occasions I only had the option to download the 5.0 simulator. Thanks for the negative rating and false claims by the way Popeye.

Comment: I think the time I got the option to download the 4.3 simulator I had updated to xcode 4.4.1 on lion before installing ML. Still the simulator wont work anyway! On the other 2 machines I installed ML, then updated to xcode 4.4.1 and didnt get the option to download 4.3 sim.

Comment: I will say again this is not clear in tour question.

Comment: It is still unclear. My recommendation is to delete the question and re-ask it making it clear. If it is not clear you will not get anyone to look and you will get down votes.

Comment: This is a valid question. Just b/c you do not know the answer does not mean you criticize (or worse mark as 'not constructive') the asker. The question, simply stated, is that can one deploy apps to iOS simulator earlier than 5.0 using Xcode 4.4.1? If so, how? (not the 'should be able to' type answers, we all know you should be able to as we've done it for years, but CAN YOU, HOW?).

Comment: Thank you Ephraim some sense and justice finally! I will tell you how I finally got around the problem - brace yourself its not the easiest (see second edit above).

Answer (score 2):

I have just commented but I have also just done it so yes it can be done.

open xcode and in the top menu go to xcode >> preferences >> Downloads  and  you will be given the option to download old sdks to use with xcode. You can also download command line tools and Device Debugging Support.

Remember to set your project to Deployment Target to ever that version or an earlier version in your target settings (Summary)

**EDIT**

Here is a [link](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) to the Apple developer downloads section you will require a username and password to login. once in deselect all search options except iOS and there you will find all the iOS's that are available to you. Be aware though that if you have anything that is in a later version and not in the previous version of iOS it will crash e.g. Storyborads (Introduced in iOS 5).

Comment: I have downloaded everything available and yes my deployment target is correct. Are you saying you have actually run an app on an ios4 simulator in xcode 4.4.1 (Mountain Lion)?

Comment: I am unsure then I was given the option to download the sdk for ios4+, ios5. And yes on Mountain Lion.

Comment: I too had the option to download 4.3 simulator - unfortuately if you try to run an app on it you will get an error. Thats why I asked have you run an App on the simulator not have you downloaded it?

Comment: If you are using features introduced into ios 5 then it will fail. And yes I have run an old version of one my apps before I introduced ios 5 features into it, and it works. You might want to update you question because if you have downloaded them then then your question to indicate that you can download them as your question gives the impression you can't. Also Apple only provide the downloads for ios versions that they are currently supporting. If you which to download old versions then you will have to visit the Apple developer website and download them from there.

Comment: You should really be doing the same thing. Supporting only the versions that Apple do plus maybe the one before. As when a version is dropped from support they would normally force the user to update to the latest ios. Unless you really want to support the old generation iphones/ipods that not a lot of people have anymore at a guess I would say that it is about 3% of users with an iPhone 3 and below. Well below the must support percentage. And I believe that 3GS is getting dropped with the release of 5. So the standard resolution images will be dropped from support so will not be required.

Comment: I have published apps on the app store that support ios4. I am fully aware of what works in ios4 and ios5 that is not the issue. I would like to see a screenshot of you running ios4 simulator in xcode 4.4.1 mountain lion. You wont be able to provide this because you cannot do it. You are claiming to be able to do something as standard practise which isnt possible. I have been through the process on 3 different Macs. Why would you want to confuse the issue in this way?

Comment: I have to support ios4 for my company it is required by them. We have a target demographic that isnt always up with the latest releases. Ios4 is the last major release before ios5 so why shouldnt I be able to support it. I could tell my boss you dont think I should support it and see how long I keep my job, but I wont.

Comment: @user1600350 Please see my edit to my answer.

Comment: Look thanks for trying to answer, but Im going to give up here. Your edit is not going to help the issue Im trying to solve of getting ios4 simulators working on xcode 4.4.1 (ML). Im aware of this download location. This is a really specific topic for those of us developers who wish to support ios4 apps. You will not see a screenshot of these claims in action because its not currently possible.